# What is the proper way to encode sets (lists of unique elements)?

Tags: agda

In Agda, what is the proper way to encode a set; i.e., a list of unique elements?

**What I've tried:**

One could do it, using one of the suggested methods on my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52196188/what-are-the-drawbacks-of-encoding-properties-using-functions#52208024), which would be to encode the predicate `is-set` as a `List A -> Set` function, and then use a Sigma to make a subset of lists that are also sets:

```
open import Data.List
open import Data.Empty
open import Data.Unit
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Product
open import Data.Bool
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Relation.Nullary

DecEq : (A : Set) -> Set
DecEq A = (a : A) -> (b : A) -> Dec (a ≡ b) 

is-in : {A : Set} -> (eq : DecEq A) -> (a : A) -> List A -> Bool
is-in eq v [] = false
is-in eq v (x ∷ xs) with eq v x 
is-in eq v (x ∷ xs) | yes p = true
is-in eq v (x ∷ xs) | no ¬p = is-in eq v xs

is-set : {A : Set} -> (eq : DecEq A) -> List A -> Set
is-set eq [] = ⊤
is-set eq (x ∷ xs) with is-in eq x xs
... | false = is-set eq xs
... | true  = ⊥

Uniques : (A : Set) -> DecEq A -> Set
Uniques A eq = Σ (List A) (is-set eq)

eq : (a : ℕ) -> (b : ℕ) -> Dec (a ≡ b)
eq zero zero = yes refl
eq zero (suc b) = no (λ ())
eq (suc a) zero = no (λ ())
eq (suc a) (suc b) with eq a b
eq (suc a) (suc b) | yes p = yes (cong suc p)
eq (suc a) (suc b) | no ¬p = no f where
  f : suc a ≡ suc b -> ⊥
  f refl = ¬p refl

set : Uniques ℕ eq
set = (1 ∷ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ []) , tt
```

Similarly, I could define an inductive type also using `is-in`. But both ideas look rather contrived, because both still rely on `is-in` which is still a `List A -> Bool` function. Thus, is there a more appropriate way to do it? Also, is such data-structure available on the standard (or other) libraries?

Comment: Also if any of those things (DecEq?) is available on standard libraries, please let me know! I'd love an article providing a tour on the standard libraries. Also, is there any better way to explore the standard libs than browsing Github?

Comment: The best way to browse is to use jump-to-definition in emacs. It's "M-." by default.

Comment: Here's a [paper](http://firsov.ee/finset/finset.pdf) about finite sets in Agda. I personally haven't worked much with them.